# Problema ao mudar o tipo de uma coluna no model usando anotação JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho uma coluna no banco de dados que é limitada a receber um `varchar(255)`, mas preciso mudar isso para um tamanho maior.

Para isso adicionei estas anotações no campo:

```
@Column(nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@Length(max = 10000)
```

Porém isso não mudou o tamanho suportado da coluna que desejo alterar. Como faço essa alteração utilizando o mapeamento JPA?

Comment: Mas essa alteração você espera acontecer após a criação do banco de dados já com a coluna criada como `varchar(255)` anteriormente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Victor Stafusa respondeu, basta usar a propriedade `length` da anotação `Column`, porem se a coluna do banco de dados já estiver criada ela somente será alterada caso a opção `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` esteja `update`, `create`, `create-drop`.

Tenha em mente que a intenção dessas opções é para ambiente de desenvolvimento, o ideal em produção é alterar o banco pelo gerenciador dele ou por algum processo de atualização.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Irei Fazer isso. A proposito o Banco é PostGreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Que tal tentar usar isso?

```java
@Column(nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 10000)
```

Aliás, você não disse qual é o banco de dados que você usou, mas seja lá qual for, este `length` tem que estar dentro deste limite. Se estiver usando o SQL Server, o DB/2 ou o MySQL, por exemplo, você poderá colocar 10000 tranquilamente. No Oracle 8 até o 11g, parece que o limite é 4000.

Uma outra alternativa:

```java
@Lob
@Column(nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15135905/540552

Comment: Agradeço pela dica Victor. Abraços!